# maven compiles java projects in jdk 1.4 mode while running java 1.7?

Tags: java, maven, pmd

I have a big maven project divided to some modules.

I decided to give the pmd (code quality check) module with maven.

when I try to test the pmd module using the command

```
mvn pmd:pmd
```

I get the following types of warnings:

- Can't use generics unless running in JDK 1.5 mode!
- Can't use annotations when running in JDK 1.4 mode!
- Can't use enum as a keyword in pre-JDK 1.5 target

looks like maven compiles the projects using jdk 1.4 for some reason.

`java -version` output:

```
java version "1.7.0_05"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea7 2.2.1) (Gentoo build 1.7.0_05-b21)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.0-b21, mixed mode)
```

I use gentoo linux.

```
Linux ufk-work 3.5.2-gentoo #1 SMP Sun Aug 19 18:58:32 IDT 2012 x86_64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux
```

`mvn -version` output:

```
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 10:44:56+0200)
Maven home: /usr/share/maven-bin-3.0
Java version: 1.7.0_05, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib64/icedtea7/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: ANSI_X3.4-1968
OS name: "linux", version: "3.5.2-gentoo", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

so any ideas how to make sure that maven will compile for jdk 1.7 and not 1.4 ?

I googled and found usage examples of the maven-compiler-plugin as found in the following url: http://twit88.com/blog/2008/03/09/maven-compile-your-application-to-be-14-15-or-16-compatible/

unfortunately the results are exactly the same.

any information regarding the issue would be greatly appreciated.

thank you so much!

kfir

## update

I tried adding the maven-compiler-plugin and the maven-pmd-plugin to my main pom.xml
but the results are exactly the same.

the updated pom.xml can view at http://bpaste.net/show/41166/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you need is to tell the target version of PMD:

```
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.1</version>
      <configuration>
          <targetJdk>1.7</targetJdk>
          <rulesets>
              <ruleset>tools/pmd-rules.xml</ruleset>
          </rulesets>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.7</source>
            <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
</build>

<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Note: A few month ago the 1.7 JDK was not supported, you should double check it in the documentation, otherwise you won't be able to use the diamond syntax.

Comment: i get the same results as before. update main post with a link to the pom.xml file.

Comment: try to move the pmd configuration in the build aera

Comment: is it ok that pmd-rules.xml doesn't exist ? i didn't create any custom rules yet.

Comment: after removing the rulesets property from the xml i got the warning: Unable to locate Source XRef to link to - DISABLED. i resolved it by executing 'mvn jxr:jxr'. i didn't really understand why I need to execute it in the first place.

Comment: yes, remove the ruleset if you don't have it. so does it works fine now?

Comment: yea seems so. it didn't complain about anything. that's a shame i wanted to see it in action. any ideas what to add to my code to see that it really works?

Comment: welp if you don't find anything that's ok.. the fact that it doesn't show the warnings it used to show means that it works. thanks

Comment: you should have a file pmd.xml in the target folder. It contains the list of issues detected by the plugin.

Comment: awesome!!! i didn't know that!!! it really works!! amazing!! it does complain about my code! i'm so happy! thanks

Answer (score 1):

In `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: it seems like it doesn't change anything. updated main post with a link to the pom file. thanks